# How do we test if a character is usually proceeded by a backslash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

When writing strings, computer programmers will often insert something called an "***escape sequence***".

For example, the string literal `"Hello World\n"` ends in a line feed character `\n`.

As another example, the string literal `"Hello World\r"` ends in a carriage return character `\r`.

How do we test whether or not a character is usually proceeded by a back-slash character?

```python
characters = [chr(num) for num in range(32, 127)]

for ch in characters:
    if is_slashed(ch):
        print(repr(ch).ljust(20), "IS SLASHED")
    else:
        print(repr(ch).ljust(20), "IS **NOT** SLASHED")
```

Suppose that `ch` is a line-feed character.

Then we have:

```None
repr(ch) == 
    [single_quote, backslash_character, the_letter_n, single_quote]
```

After that, we have...

```None
    repr(ch)[1:-2] == 
    [backslash, letter n]
```

Can we test `repr(ch)[1:-2][0] == backslash`?

Why is there an error message in the following code?

```python
characters = [chr(num) for num in range(32, 127)]

for ch in characters:
   if not repr(ch)[1:-2][0] == "\\":
       print(ch)
```

Comment: You will not get "backslash n" for `\n` but single ASCII LF (10) unless this is raw string

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I made a mistake. I wrote `letter n` instead of `letter_n`. The call to `__eq__` used in `repr(ch)[1:-2] ==  [backslash, letter_n]` returns `True` if we previously make the assignments `backslash = '\\'` and `letter_n = 'n'`

Comment: Don't write `if not something == somethingelse:`. Use `if something != somethingelse:`

Comment: There is an index error because the repr of "normal" characters is too short for your comparison

Comment: Probably what you want is `if len(repr(ch)) > 3 and repr(ch)[1] == "\\":`

Comment: "How do we test whether or not a character is usually proceeded by a back-slash character?" What do you mean by "usually"? "Why is there an error message in the following code?"  This is a separate question, and answering it starts with **reading** the error message and trying to understand it, and attempting your own [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); we don't provide a debugging service. If you are still stuck, show a [mre] with a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) error message, and ask specifically about that.

Comment: (As a hint: did you try to check the result of, for example, `repr('a')[1:-2]`? What result did you get?)

Comment: Finally: please carefully note the difference between [preceded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/preceded) and [proceeded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proceeded). Clear communication is important for programmers.

Answer (score 1):

next time you post, you should also post the error you get.
I ran the code and got a string index out of range caused by the `[1:-2]` which if you replace with `[1]` like this

```
characters = [chr(num) for num in range(32, 127)]

for ch in characters:
   if not repr(ch)[1][0] == "\\":
       print(repr(ch))
```